# git commit do not make it to the remote server

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a remote git repository and I have cloned one branch
git clone -b branchName git@servername:/home/myproject.git

I make changes in my cloned repo and I commit.
I run a git log --pretty=oneline and I see my commit message

I then go a git push

I do another re-clone and I do not see my last commit
On the repository server, I run a git log --pretty=oneline and I do not see the last commit.

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: Please show the output from the `git push`, also what does `git status` show, finally did you `checkout` the branch the second time?

Comment: Assuming your push didn't return any errors, you have to do `git checkout branchName` to see your changes in the clone/remote.

Comment: Rather than trying to explain what you did or what you think you did, just explain in a sentence or two what you think is wrong and give the EXACT command you used. Eg - you just say you re-cloned. Did you specify the branch again or not?

Comment: when do you clone and when do you checkout? I obviously cloned the first time around and committed my changes. I do see the log entry, on the remote server, if I look at the log for my cloned branch. Then I go to a different directory and clone again and I do not the latest changes... THe second time, I should checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
git log --pretty=oneline branchname
```

(or do `git checkout branchname` and then do `git log`)

to verify if the commit is there or not. Otherwise you might have been checking the log of master.

If that is not the problem, make sure your push did go through fine and you did not receive some errors.

PS: It is also a good practice to do `git push origin branchname`, especially if you are creating a new branch and also you want to push this branch alone.

Comment: I do see the log for my branch commit... So why when I reclone the same branch in a totally new place, do I not see my changes